# Search feature for json api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

So i have a list of people and additional information about them which I got from a json array, I now want to make a search feature that when a name is typed in, the person and some of their information is shown.

What is the best way to do this e.g pure Javascript or just jQuery ?
Any leads/ push in the right direction is much appreciated.

JSON sample

```
{
GetContactsResult: [
  {
    FirstName: "John",
    ImageHash: "DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709",
    IsFavourite: false,
    LastName: "Doe",
    LocalNumber: null,
    MobileNumber: null,
    PhoneState: 2,
    StateCaption: "Busy",
    StateColor: {
    B: 128,
    G: 128,
    R: 255
          },
    StateEnd: "/Date(-2209161600000)/",
    StateHasEnd: false,
    StateSubject: "Busy",
   UserRecID: 62376
 },
{
   FirstName: "Jane",
   ImageHash: "DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709",
   IsFavourite: false,
   LastName: "Doe",
   LocalNumber: null,
   MobileNumber: null,
   PhoneState: 2,
   StateCaption: "At work",
   StateColor: {
   B: 128,
   G: 128,
   R: 255
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json.GetContactsResult.filter(function(person) {
    return person.FirstName == "John";
});
```

This returns an array with the people whose first name is "John".